# PHP shell execution create dynamic command

Tags: php

Following Command search a file in a directory and zip it,it works well

```
  $command = "cd {$root}/files && mkdir -p {$identifier} && zip -jFS -0 {$root}{$zipname}  2491/'test&.txt'";
  exec($command);
```

But changing files as variable is not allowing shell to execute,the below code does not work

```
$container_name = "2491";
$files = Array ( '0' => 'test&.txt' ,'1' => 'test5.txt','2' => 'test6.txt');
$files = " " . $container_name . "/'" . implode("' " . $container_name . "/'", $files) . "'";
$files = str_replace('$', '\$', $files);
$command = "cd {$root}/files && mkdir -p {$identifier} && zip -jFS -0 {$root}{$zipname} {$files}";
exec($command);
```

$root,$identifier,$zipname not causing the problem,its $files What can be the issue?

**Update**

var_dump for $command before execution:

```
string(128) "cd /var/www/files && mkdir -p zip--1 && zip -jFS -0 /var/www/files/zip--1/1002_22-06022-06022-_content.zip 2491/'test&.txt'"
```

which if I execute as

```
exec("cd /var/www/files && mkdir -p zip--1 && zip -jFS -0 /var/www/files/zip--1/1002_22-06022-06022-_content.zip 2491/'test&.txt'");
```

runs perfectly

**Error Reponse:**

zip error: Nothing to do! (/var/www/files/zip--1/1002_22-06022-06022-_content.zip)

Comment: Can you post the output of the `$command` variable after execution?

Comment: Before you execute the command, dump it, and check, is it exactly the same as when you not use variables.

Comment: @preinheimer getting zip error: Nothing to do! (/var/www/files/zip--1/1002_22-06022-06022-_content.zip) as command execution response.

Comment: @preinheimer var_dump of command after execution looks like  "cd /var/www/files && mkdir -p zip--1 && zip -jFS -0 /var/www/files/zip--1/1002_22-06022-06022-_content.zip 2491/'test&.txt'"

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it clear.  Which of your commands is giving you the `zip error: Nothing to do!` message?  The command before it says it "runs perfectly".

Answer (score 0):

I got it fix, issue was with file name having `'&'` which was chanding to `'&amp;'`, thus breaking the command. To get it I passed through the file name with [htmlspecialchars_decode].[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)